# Avoid duplicate Tabs in QTabWidget

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

I have an application, in which I have added a QTabWidget.
Tabs are closable.
When I add new tab, if the tab is already added, it still add new tab and make duplicate.
I want to avoid this duplication.
If the tab is opened already then It just active that tab and not open again.
You help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To add on top of Prakash's answer, be aware that some times the tab title is not a good identifier of the content of the tab (this of course depends on the situation). For example, you might have a file manager where the current directory is the title of the tab, but there might be different directories with the same name across your filesystem.

I would follow the following strategy for identifying tab contents: Qt allows you to set dynamical properties to widgets (see [QObject::setProperty](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setProperty)), so each time you create a new tab, for example of a file manager, you might do something like

```
widget = ...
widget->setProperty("tab_dir_fullpath", the_full_path);
tabWidget->addWidget(widget, directory_name);
```

where `the_full_path` would be a unique identifier (in this example, the full absolute path to the current directory), which will not be displayed to the user but which you can later use to see if a given directory is already open.

Then, when opening a new tab, you should check whether the same full path is already open:

```
for (int k = 0; k < tabWidget->count(); ++k) {
  if (tabWidget->widget(k)->property("tab_dir_fullpath").toString() == the_full_path_to_open) {
    tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(k);
    return;
  }
}

... // open new tab, as in the previous snippet.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use tabText(int index) to get the identifier of the each tab before adding a new tab addTab(QWidget * page, const QString & label) and compare the label texts, if already exist just setCurrentIndex of that index or else add a new tab.

Comment: I have done it. 
 for(int i=0;i<tabWidget->count();i++)
    {
        if(item->text()==tabWidget->tabText(i))
        {
            tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(i);
            return;
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Noor Nawaz's comment, my approch is:

```
    void MainWindow::openPanel1()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<ui->tabWidget->count();i++) {
            if(ui->tabWidget->tabText(i) == "Panel1") {
                ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(i);
                return;
            }
        }
        Panel1 = new panel1Widget();
        int index = ui->tabWidget->addTab(Panel1,"Panel1");
        ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also its very good to use setTabData() instead of property which is more proper way of doing.